# Link to pdf file on network drive (UNC)

Tags: links, paths

I would like to put a link to an external file in a presentation, but the file is located on a network drive, so I may only get an UNC path like:

```
\\server\folder\file.pdf
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Thank you in advance,
Adam

Comment: Try
`\documentclass[demo]{beamer}`
`\begin{document}`
`\begin{frame}{UNCLINK}`
`\href{file://///server/folder/file.pdf}{Link to a file at a NETWORK drive}`
`\end{frame}`
`\end{document}`

Comment: Searched everywhere, @AkiraKakuto's solution is the only one that works. You should consider making it an answer! :D

Comment: thanks, this works, but it should be file://// (only 4 slashes). In case you want to link to a directory in stead of a file you must end with /. (the dot represents a file)